# Bika LIMS samples page does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, plone, zope, plone-4.x

I have installed Bika LIMS in Virtual Machine using ssh, which works fine except for the [Samples page](https://s24.postimg.org/s8ozo8wr9/Page_Error.png).This page loads correctly when running in localhost.

The error log doesn't say anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `samples` pages does not exist, or the `view`, `default_page` is no reachable. Probably you need to login. Further, 404 are no logged to the Z2 log by default, You can change this in the ZMI --> error_log.

Comment: I have logged in as a admin using credentials which was a adminPassword.txt file generated during buildout.

Comment: Also I created a new user and logged in through the credentials. Still getting same error. Any help?

Comment: Well I'm not able to help further... I don't know this package...

Comment: Please provide the version of bika.lims, Plone, the OS distribution and version.

I just ran into this problem today with https://github.com/bikalabs/bika.custom which pulled down bika.lims 3.1.12

Comment: Your best bet for Bika support is not here. See https://www.bikalims.org/support-and-service-provision.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, bika.lims version = 3.1.12  and Plone-4.3.11-r1-UnifiedInstaller.

Comment: I've raised a issue on https://jira.bikalabs.com/browse/LIMS-2469 But no response.

Comment: I figured it out that  bika.lims version = 3.1.12 is causing this. 3.1.11 works fine.